# Inno Setup Editable/External license file

Tags: inno-setup

I want to create a Inno Setup with a license loaded from an external file, so that it is editable. Is this possible?

The license should be excluded from the installer .exe file, but in the same folder/path.

Comment: Do you want the user to be able to edit the license in the wizard? Or do you just want to have the installer load the license from an external file?

Comment: I want to have the installer load the license from an external file.
For example: I give the installer via CD to a person. This person should be able to edit the license-file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the [`LicenseFile` directive](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_licensefile) to a default license file, to make the installer create the *"License Agreement"* page. And also to have some fallback license, in case the external license does not exist.

And then in the [`InitializeWizard` event function](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptevents&anchor=InitializeWizard) load the external license, if it exists.

```pascal
[Setup]
LicenseFile=default_license.txt

[Code]

procedure InitializeWizard();
var
  LicenseFile: string;
begin
  LicenseFile := ExpandConstant('{src}\license.txt');
  if FileExists(LicenseFile) then
  begin
    Log(Format('%s exists, loading a license', [LicenseFile]));
    WizardForm.LicenseMemo.Lines.LoadFromFile(LicenseFile);
  end
    else
  begin
    Log(Format('%s does not exist, keeping the default license', [LicenseFile]));
  end;
end;
```